# How do I stop NSURLSessionD from starting every time I restart my Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have to use the following script to terminate it every time I restart my Macbook:

```
#!/bin/sh
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plist
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plist
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist
```

Is there a way to permanently prevent it from starting?

Comment: Are you using Safari ?

Comment: Well in principle you could save your script as your own LaunchAgent, but I  wonder why you would want to kill a harmless Apple-provided API that allows other programs to download data? This could potentially lead to weird errors in the long run…

Comment: Because it downloads petabytes of unknown stuff without your consent at the most inappropriate times, especially when you're on a low-bandwidth, expensive connection and you're in a hurry. You don't know who's using it, you don't know what's downloading, you only know that your connection is clogged by the same computer you're desperately trying to use.

Answer (score 3):

To permanently unload an agent or a daemon simply add a -w.

Example:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist
```

However, the long term solution would be to identify what application is requesting downloads and controlling it. As an analogy, you can shut down a road temporarily to stop traffic, but long term, you want to control access to the road itself and not stop all traffic because some users are abusing or overloading the roadway.

Comment: Unrecognized subcommand: -w

Comment: In El Capitan: `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist: Could not find specified service`

Comment: The "-w" needs to be put after the unload subcommand: i.e. `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist`